# Does the Skyrim Prima Guide book include access to the online eGuide?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

...and interactive map?

The descriptions for the hard copy book vary a bit in online shops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My copy of the collector's edition just arrived: it included a code to unlock the [Jumbo Map Pack](http://www.primagames.com/games/elder-scrolls-v-skyrim/primaguides/243/introduction), but not the eGuide.

Looking on Amazon, the [description for the collector's edition](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0307891402) mentions this perk, but the [description for the paperback version](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0307891372) does not: it's likely that only the collector's edition got free access to the map.

Comment: Thanks for that. What's the online map like? Any good?

Comment: @Dan It's annoying to use: it takes a few seconds and reloads every time you search for something, and it only loads one hold at a time. The hard copy included with the guide is more useful.